# Counting letters in parameter string: upper case/lower case difficulty

Tags: python, uppercase, lowercase, namedtuple

```
import namedtuple
Count = namedtuple('Count', 'letter number')

def letter_count(a: str, b:str):
    '''Takes String A and count how many times a letter appears in it'''
    Countlist = []
    letter= ''
    for x in b:
        letter = x
        number=0
        for y in a:
            if y.lower() in x:
                number+=1
        Countlist.append(Count(letter, number))
    return Countlist
```

The code is supposed to work like this:
print(letter_count('Princess', 'ps')) should yield:

```
[Count(letter='p', number=0), Count(letter='s', number=1)]
```

However, I've set up the code so it's only sensitive to lowercase letters, but counts the upper case, so the result I get is:

```
[Count(letter='p', number=1), Count(letter='s', number=1)]
```

How can I make this code sensitive to both upper-case and lower-case letters?

Comment: Slightly unrelated, but you might want to look at the built-in `collections.Counter`.

Comment: For the assignment, I have to make my own function definition.

Comment: You are forced to make your own NamedTuple? A function definition is something else.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `.lower()` method call?

Comment: Oops, and yup--the directions say: Write a function called letter_count, so I'm guessing the professor won't allow us to use any built-in resources. 

Edit: The instructions say "For the purpose of this problem, treat upper and lower case characters as distinct, but you should modify your function to count upper and lower case versions of the same letter together.

Comment: I don't think anyone would object to you using Counter instead of namedtuple - they're both part of Python, just like lists, sets, etc. A Counter is more aligned to the task you're trying to achieve - and you will still need to use it within your function.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's actually specified that we have to create the Count namedtuple to proceed.

Comment: Fair enough - good luck solving it anyway! One extra comment I would make is the line `letter = x` is a bit pointless as it is, as you later on still use x anyway. The code would be much clearer if you removed that line and made the previous line `for letter in b:`. Then you could do similar things renaming the `a` and `b` variables to something more meaningful e.g. `target` and `count_letters`.

Comment: Got it, thanks for your help!